# How can we make day numbers bold in date picker?

Tags: flutter, material-design

Is there a way to customize day numbers, i.e. change font style, font weight, color?

Comment: Which dart library you used for date picker?

Comment: @NikunjM I am using the default one by `showDatePicker()` method